# How to trigger AMP script when in viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, viewport, amp-html, web-worker

Here is my implementation of counters using javascript on AMP page:

Frontend Screenshot:

[image]

JS:

```
<script id="counter-async" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">

    const obj = document.querySelector('.counter-wrap');
    let cDataEnd = obj.getAttribute('data-cend');

    function animateValue(obj, start, end, duration) {
      let startTimestamp = null;
      const step = (timestamp) => {
        if (!startTimestamp) startTimestamp = timestamp;
        const progress = Math.min((timestamp - startTimestamp) / duration, 1);
        obj.innerHTML = Math.floor(progress * (end - start) + start);
        if (progress < 1) {
          window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        }
      };
      window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
    animateValue(obj, 0, cDataEnd, 1500);   

</script>
```

AMP Script:

```
<amp-script layout="fill" script="counter-async" class="amp-script-counter" data-ampdevmode="">
   <span data-cend="9" class="counter-wrap">0</span>
   <label class="postfix">&#65122;</label>
</amp-script>
```

It executes immediately after page load and as soon as the counters block is at the end of the page I can't see digits animation unless I reload a page when the block is in the viewport.

Is there a way to run a script when the counters block is in the viewport using amp position observer or any other method?

Comment: amp-script executes in a web worker so I am not sure if it's possible

Comment: @MilindMore I see, so the only solution is to get offset using another function and call `animateValue` function in it?